# How can we check if an arbitrary shape covers a box (partially, fully, or not) if we can only evaluate the shape pointwise?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have described an [algorithm for generating random points inside an arbitrary shape](https://peteroupc.github.io/morealg.html#Uniform_Distribution_Inside_N_Dimensional_Shapes) (such as a circle, polygon, or an arbitrary closed curve) contained within a box. It involves checking whether the box is outside or partially or fully inside the shape, and then—

- Generating a uniform random point inside the box if the box is inside the shape,
- rejecting the box and starting over if the box is outside the shape, and
- subdividing the box, choosing a random sub-box, and repeating this process for that sub-box otherwise.

This algorithm uses a function called **InShape** that determines whether a shape covers an axis-aligned bounding box. (See also my [question on Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3882545/what-conditions-ensure-that-checking-if-a-shape-covers-a-box-can-be-done-just-by).) It takes such a bounding box as input and returns—

- *YES* if the box is entirely inside the shape;
- *NO* if the box is entirely outside the shape; and
- *MAYBE* if the box is partly inside and partly outside the shape.

Now, take a particular implementation of **InShape** that has certain knowledge about a particular shape. Assume the following:

- The shape is closed, has nonzero finite volume, and has a boundary of measure zero.
- The **InShape** implementation can determine only *pointwise* whether a point is either outside the shape, or on or inside the shape.
- The **InShape** implementation has access to arbitrary-precision arithmetic, as well as interval arithmetic using arbitrary-precision rational numbers. See [my library](https://github.com/peteroupc/peteroupc.github.io/blob/master/interval.py), for example.
- Other than this, it doesn't matter how the shape is described -- it could be described as a sequence of line and/or curve segments describing the shape's outline; as a signed distance function; as an inequality; as a union or intersection of multiple shapes; etc.

The **InShape** implementation is given an axis-aligned bounding box as input. The goal is to correctly classify the box just by evaluating the shape *pointwise*.

Under certain conditions, this is trivial to do. For example, if the shape is enclosed by a 1x1 rectangle, the point (0, 0) is on the shape, and every horizontal or vertical line crosses the shape (inside the rectangle) at most once (think of one quarter of a circle centered at the origin), then the box can be correctly classified just by checking the point's corners. The algorithm (Algorithm 1) is thus to return—

- *YES* if all the box's vertices are on or inside the shape;
- *NO* if none of the box's vertices are on or inside the shape; and
- *MAYBE* in any other case.

However, for more general convex shapes (which are the shapes that I care about most), this is not so easy. For example, if the shape is convex and the point (0, 0) is on the shape, the correct algorithm to classify the shape (Algorithm 2) is to return—

- *YES* if all the box's vertices are on or inside the shape;
- *NO* if none of the box's vertices are on or inside the shape *and if the shape's boundary does not intersect the box's boundary*; and
- *MAYBE* in any other case.

This is not so easy because checking whether a box intersects a shape might not be robust especially if the shape is described by an inequality (such as `x^2 + y^2 - 1 <= 0`). Under certain cases, the algorithm might miss an intersection even though it's present. But at least when the shape is convex and when **InShape** uses interval arithmetic and builds one interval for each dimension of the box (here, [*x*, *x*+ε] and [*y*, *y*+ε]), and evaluates the inequality only once with the intervals, **InShape** can still get robust results. In this algorithm (Algorithm 3), **InShape** returns—

- *YES* if the result's upper bound is less than 0;
- *NO* if the result's lower bound is greater than 0; and
- *MAYBE* in any other case.

Thus my questions are:

1. What are necessary and/or sufficient conditions (such as convexity or regularity conditions, or other requirements on the shape) that allow Algorithm 1 to work correctly?
2. What are necessary and/or sufficient conditions that allow Algorithm 2 to work correctly, if the **InShape** method can only evaluate the shape point-by-point? In particular, how can Algorithm 2 robustly check for intersections as required to determine whether to return *NO* or *MAYBE*?
3. Does Algorithm 3 work for nonconvex shapes? Are there any shapes where this algorithm fails to be correct (taking into account the assumptions in this post)?
4. What are other conditions that allow **InShape** to correctly classify whether a box is outside or on or inside a shape when **InShape** can only evaluate the shape point-by-point, or when **InShape** proceeds as in Algorithm 3?

---

**Examples:**

Take the following shapes, all of which are convex and equal 0 at the origin:

- `v^2 - (u/v)^(1.4-1)*exp(-(u/v)) <= 0` - Ratio-of-uniforms shape for the gamma(1.4) distribution
- `v^2 - exp(-(u/v)^2/2) <= 0` - Ratio-of-uniforms shape for the normal distribution
- `v^2 - (u/v)^2*exp(-(u/v)^2/2) <= 0` - Ratio-of-uniforms shape for the Maxwell distribution

All three shapes don't work under Algorithm 1, but they appear to give correct results under Algorithm 3, even without the intersection checks required by Algorithm 2.

Comment: If I am right, when the shape is convex, all corners inside is a necessary and sufficient condition for a YES answer. In all other cases (not convex or some corners in, some out), there is no finite procedure that can conclude anything. IMO the problem is a generalization of a general 1D root solver.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64728693/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3882545/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to infer much about a convex body with only point membership tests. If it weren't so, convex programming would be much easier. Still, it is possible to get useful work done – if you have a bound on the Vapnik–Chervonenkis dimension of the class of shapes that you're sampling, then it may be possible through PAC learning to make high-quality predictions about other points. I don't think this helps you though, since it's not exact.

Since you mention interval arithmetic, I think that's probably the way to go here. The examples that you give involve standard functions and can all be handled easily by (e.g.) [Boost's interval arithmetic library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm). It's not a problem to get a MAYBE that should be a YES or a NO as long as you don't hit an infinite string of MAYBEs, so even if the intervals are a little loose, the algorithm will still be fine. What may cause a problem is if you are unlucky and hit the negligible boundary region that can't be resolved in double precision. In that case you could either shrug and accept a very small statistical distance to the true distribution or fall back to your own interval arithmetic implementation with bignum fractions (but you'd potentially have to implement your own transcendental functions).

Comment: What is the Vapnik–Chervonenkis dimension?  I have now given examples of shapes I care about; how does your answer relate to those examples?

Comment: @PeterO. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension, but I do think interval arithmetic, possibly with bignum fractions, is the way to go.

Comment: That last point in your edited answer is no problem at all: I have already implemented a [rational interval arithmetic library](https://github.com/peteroupc/peteroupc.github.io/blob/master/interval.py).  Assume I already have this library in place.  Then, for example, Algorithm 1 could be implemented by returning _YES_ if the upper bounds for each corner are less than 0; _NO_ if the lower bounds are greater than 0; or _MAYBE_ otherwise; I knew this before I asked this question.

Comment: My question is what conditions on the shape will allow Algorithm 1 to be correct, assuming it uses rational interval arithmetic, so that there would be no need to use a more complicated check, such as Algorithm 2 or an even complexer algorithm.  Similarly for Algorithm 2, similarly for some other algorithm that evaluates the shape only pointwise, using rational interval arithmetic.

Comment: @PeterO. I'm confused by your references to the vertices of the box. Given that you have axis-aligned boxes, you should set up the intervals to exactly match the box and then evaluate the LHS of the inequality once using interval arithmetic. Is this just Algorithm 1?

Comment: I was referring to each interval representing _each_ vertex of the box.  Since the functions in the inequality involve irrational numbers and transcendental functions, the intervals for each vertex will be loose, so that checking the interval's upper and lower bounds would be necessary.  On the other hand, if the inequality involved only rational numbers, rational arithmetic would suffice to determine whether a vertex lies in the shape.  I didn't consider much the idea of treating each _dimension_ of the box as an interval.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion (now Algorithm 3 in my question) with several convex shapes and it appears to work well.  In my [implementation notes](https://peteroupc.github.io/morealg.html#Implementation_Notes_for_Box_Shape_Intersection), I say in note 3 that it appears to work at least for convex shapes (and also it appears to work at least if (0,...,0) is on or inside the shape).  But does it also work for concave shapes?  Are there any closed shapes where this algorithm fails?

Comment: @PeterO. Safety is guaranteed by the interval arithmetic implementation on all shapes -- if Algorithm 3 returns a sample, it's good. Liveness is another story. Intuitively you need not to get stuck with an infinite chain of MAYBEs. I think it could be possible to get a clean characterization assuming that the interval arithmetic returns the infimum and supremum over the box, but of course in general it doesn't, which makes the problem messier. I think this question is worth dragging over to math.SE to see what they say since I don't deal in these abstractions very much.

Comment: This question was cross-posted.  Please consider adding your answer to Math Stack Exchange.